# Text tokenization where token can contain multiple words with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to implement some NER with gamespot's articles. Now i should tokenize text and transform it to BIO format. For it i'm going to using pyspark.
For example I have some text and list of video games:

```
text = "Dead Space Remake Is Only $28 At GameFly."
games = ["Dead Space", "Dead Space Remake", "Witcher 3"]
```

After using Tokenizer i receive the following:

```
df = wordDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, "Dead Space Remake Is Only $28 At GameFly.")],
    ["id", "text"])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='text', outputCol='token_text')
df = tokenizer.transform(df) #  result ["dead", "space", "remake", "is", ...]
```

But how can i make Tokenizer do not split words from games list and receive something like this:

```
["dead space remake", "is", ...]
```

Comment: What's the logic behind your tokenization ? do you group each 3 words or something like that ?

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb if you are asking about the implementation of Tokenizer class it's a class of pyspark.ml.feature package. I don't group each 3 words, I'm just interested if i can make Tokenizer don't split my tokens (["Dead Space", "Dead Space Remake", "Witcher 3"]) and work with them like with other separated tokens